# MATLAB's Serial Port Performance

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am currently working on a GUI-based application that records serial data from an embedded system that is transmitted at 50Hz. The problem is that MATLAB appears incapable of recording this data reliably, and drops samples. The format of the transmitted data is as follows:

```
4918  22279  29342   3161      0  24953  29814   5319      1      0
4919  22279  29348   2997      1  24953  29838   5037      0      0
4920  22279  29357   2682      0  24953  29853   4544      0      0
```

Each row is terminated by a CR/LF. I have written a test function to try and figure out what is going on - the code for this is below.

```
function stack_stream(time)
    column_count = 10;

    serial_object = create_serial_object;
    fopen(serial_object);

    date_vector = clock;
    file_name = datestr(date_vector,30);
    file_name = [file_name '.txt'];

    file_identifier = fopen(file_name,'w');
    tic;

    while (toc < time)
        if (serial_object.UserData.is_new_data == true)
            raw_chunk = serial_object.UserData.data;
            serial_object.UserData.is_new_data = false;

            data_chunk = sscanf(raw_chunk,'%d');
            data_chunk_length = length(data_chunk);

            if (mod(data_chunk_length,column_count) == 0)
                data_column_count = data_chunk_length/column_count;

                data = reshape(data_chunk,column_count,data_column_count);

                fprintf(file_identifier,...
                    '%6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d %6d\r\n',data);
            end
        end
    end

    fclose(file_identifier);
    fclose(serial_object);
    delete(serial_object);
end

function serial_object_callback(object,event)
    new_data = fscanf(object,'%c',object.BytesAvailable);

    if (object.UserData.is_new_data == false)
        object.UserData.data = new_data;
        object.UserData.is_new_data = true;
    else
        object.UserData.data = [object.UserData.data new_data];
    end
end

function serial_object = create_serial_object()
    serial_object = serial('COM2');

    serial_object.BaudRate = 57600;
    serial_object.DataBits = 8;
    serial_object.FlowControl = 'none';
    serial_object.StopBits = 1;

    serial_object.Terminator = 'CR/LF';
    serial_object.InputBufferSize = 2^18;
    serial_object.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
    serial_object.BytesAvailableFcn = {@serial_object_callback};

    serial_object.UserData.data = [];
    serial_object.UserData.is_new_data = false;
    serial_object.UserData.response = [];
    serial_object.UserData.is_new_response = false;
end
```

In essence, this function writes `time` seconds worth of data to file, using a callback to transfer data between the serial object buffer and a user buffer. Using `stack_stream` I find that I miss around 10 rows of data for every 3000 received - ie about 10 a minute.

Anecdotal evidence would lead me to believe that MATLAB is capable of handling serial data in the kHz range, so I am at somewhat of a loss to determine why I cannot get it to work properly at a paltry 50Hz. Is there anything I can do to improve performance without having to resort to the real-time target for windows or the like?

Comment: Isn't this "normal" for any serial port? I remember having to write lots of code to check data integrity for data going over RS422/485 connections, exactly because of this sort of problem...and that was in C and had nothing to do with MATLAB. If I remember correctly, the data is sent as-is, and there is no error checking mechanism whatsoever in any of the standard protocols. Therefore, mechanical things like length of the cable, quality of the connection, etc. matter a lot for the success rate. But please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The behavior is not normal. If I use Hyperterminal to record the data being sent from the embedded system to file, rather than MATLAB, I can leave it running for hours and not miss a single row of data (each row of data is enumerated, so its easy to figure out what is missing). I am convinced the problem is MATLAB-specific, although I am happy to be proven incorrect.